# Did I just convert my ada to a wrapped/pegged token?

Tags: wallet, ada, daedalus, ledger

I purchased ada on binance us and for some dumb reason, I used the BEP2 network vs the Cardano network to send my ada on binance us to Daedalus/ledger. It all shows up in Daedalus as ADA but after reading some threads did I just convert this to a wrapped token vs a native token? I'm still pretty new to this and may be misunderstanding this, but I want to ensure the ada I have in my Daedalus wallet is the native token and not wrapped or pegged, and if it is what do I need to do to get back the native token? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you use the [Daedalus mainnet client](https://daedaluswallet.io/en/download/) and see your balance, you are using ADA.

To be absolutely sure you can copy your public address and look it up on the cardano explorer: https://explorer.cardano.org/en/address?address=YOUR_ADDRESS

Example:
https://explorer.cardano.org/en/address?address=addr1qy273uqgsnv2v9hrllgp32g4gkxke85d8nsk4nup6t354kyluklkqpppvma530cs4se0gd46m5njrwtqraknat2ef9rq4v2my2

There you'll be able to see your ADA balance

[image]

Comment: Dude! Thank you so much, I've spent hours looking for this answer and after utilizing this tool I was able to verify that I did actually use the cardano network and all is good, thank you so much, this was super helpful, now I can go to bed:)

Comment: @ChristopherJManganello glad eddex was able to help you. Make sure to upvote and accept the answer, so others can see that this issue has been solved for you.

Comment: Got it, thank you all so much, this is a wonderful community so far:)